# canon CUPS color print is not good

Tags: printing, cups

i have a **Canon Pixma G1411 printer** and I'm trying to print  **glossy 4x6 photos** from my Raspberry Pi. I have already installed CUPS (Common Unix Printing System) and selected the

> "Canon PIXMA G1400 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.3.3"

drivers. However, I'm facing a color issue where there is a significant difference in color output compared to when I print the same photos from Windows.

if i print image as it is its  prints like faded colors,  if i go to photoshop and change image to cmyk  then when i print it it show to dark, but colors are not as in windows (i dont know how to explain).

Is there a way to fix the color mismatch and achieve similar results to those obtained when printing from Windows?

maybe need to update profile or install different drivers

Comment: `maybe need to update profile or install different drivers` - probably. Why are you using G1400 for G411 model? Did something say they are correct?

Comment: `(i dont know how to explain).` ... post pictures then